# Как передать коллекцию комплексного типа в процедуру?

Tags: python, oracle, plsql, cx-oracle

Есть процедура в пакете:

```
create or replace package pack as
    type arr is table of number index by pls_integer;
    procedure proc (par arr);
end;
/
```

Согласно гл. [Binding PL/SQL Collections](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-pl-sql-collections), такой код для вызова этой процедуры работает:

```
arr = [1,2,3]
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.callproc ("pack.proc2", [arr])
```

Хочу теперь вызывать процедуру с коллекцией комплексного типа:

```
create or replace package pack as
    type rec is record (id int, name varchar2 (8));
    type tab is table of rec;
    procedure proc (par tab);
end;
/
```

В документации, откуда взят рабочий пример выше, о коллекциях с комплексным типом данных вообще не упоминается.

Как можно передать коллекцию комплексного типа в процедуру?

Answer (score 2):

Объявленные в PL/SQL [записи](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#binding-pl-sql-records) и коллекции с ними являются расширением к DB API, и должны быть получены как объекты типа [ObjectType](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/object_type.html#) из соединения.

Подготовка схемы для воспроизводимого примера:

```
create table t (id int, name varchar2 (8));

create or replace package pack as
    type rec is record (id int, name varchar2 (8));
    type tab is table of rec;
    procedure proc (par tab);
end;
/
create or replace package body pack as
    procedure proc (par tab) is 
    begin
        forall i in indices of par
            insert into t values (par(i).id, par(i).name);
    end;
end;
/
```

Код вызова процедуры:

```
from cx_Oracle import connect 

conn = connect ('connect_string')
recobj = conn.gettype ("PACK.REC")
tabobj = conn.gettype ("PACK.TAB")

tab = tabobj.newobject ()
rec = recobj.newobject ()
rec.ID = 1
rec.NAME = "aaa"
tab.append (rec)
rec = recobj.newobject ()
rec.ID = 2
rec.NAME = "bbb"
tab.append (rec)

with conn.cursor () as cursor:
    cursor.callproc ("pack.proc", [tab])
conn.commit ()
```

Результат:

```
select * from t
/
        ID NAME    
---------- --------
         1 aaa     
         2 bbb
```